# How to display form module in two coloms?

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I again looking for your help.
I have a form module that should be displayed in two coloms, like this one:
http://www.quickbase.com/help/images/form_example.gif

I did a lot of researches for how to solve this and couldn't find so much.

1. do I need both functions `hook_form_alter` and `hook_theme`?
2. should they look like this?

   ```
   function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_data, $form_id){ if(stripos($form, 'my_module_form') === 0 && $form['#parameters'][2]->type =='product') {
           $form_data['#theme']  = 'mytemplate';
            }
   }

   function my_module_theme() 
       {
             return array(
               'my_module_form' => array(
                 'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
                 'template' => 'mytemplate',
               ),
             );
           }
   ```
3. What should contain file mytemplate.tpl.php ?

**Here is part of my form:**

```
function my_module_form($form_data) {
    $form['contact_information'] = array(
        '#value' => variable_get('contact_form_information', t('Please fill in all fields.'))
    );
    $form['first'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('First name'),
        '#maxlength' => 20,
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['last'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Last name'),
        '#maxlength' => 20,
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['street'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Street Address'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
ect
```

**Finally I solved it:**

```
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks['my_module_form'] = array(
    'template' => 'mytemplate',
    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
  );
  return $hooks;
}
```

and here is mytemplate.tpl.php

```
<div style="float:right; width: 100%; height:20px; text-align:left;"> 
        <?php print_r(drupal_render($form['contact_information'])); ?>
    </div>
<div style="margin-top: -1em;">
    <div style="float:left;"> 
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['first'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;"> 
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['last'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;"> 
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['street'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;"> 
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['city'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">  
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['postal'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; width:385px;">     
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['state'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['mobile'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; ">
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['ext'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['phone'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['home_phone'])); ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <strong><?php print_r(drupal_render($form['email'])); ?></strong>
    </div>  
</div>

    <div style="background-color:#EEEEEE;
        float:left; 
        margin-bottom: -5%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align:right;"> 
                <?php echo drupal_render($form['submit']),
                            drupal_render($form['clear']); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: I'm on drupal 6 now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the markup-type in your form array to group form items and then style the groups.
The code below will wrap the three items with a div which has the class **column-left**. Do the same for the right column.

To clear things up: The **column_left**-item is of the type **markup**, which is the default type.

```
$form['column_left'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="column-left">', 
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
$form['column_left']['first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First name'),
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['column_left']['last'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last name'),
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['column_left']['street'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Street Address'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

For Drupal 7, you can use the container-type and use the attributes array to add the class. A div is generated automatically.

```
$form['column_left'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('column-left'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you @hampusn for your quick respond, this is the easiest way to do that. What about do this using a function? Do you know what I need for?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you. What exactly are you asking? You should use that structure in your `hook_form()` function.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I trying to say that method which you described above I used it before, it's good one but not the perfect one :), I would like to find out how to create a custom theme for my form, using hook_theme.

Comment: But that is actually the correct way to do it. I think you're making this overly complicated for yourself. For example, there is no reason to have a `hook_form_alter` when the changes you want to make can already be put in your `hook_form`.

Comment: you absolutely right here:), but, the reason why I'm doing this module is to understand how drupal works and how to create custom themes for individual module, in this case is contact info form.

Comment: hampusn, can you help to solve this by adding a theme to form?

Comment: What exactly isn't working with the code you have posted above? Have you looked at how they do it in the upload module? Go to  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21upload%21upload.module/6 and look at the source. Or look at it directly in your drupal installation: `/modules/upload/upload.module`.

Comment: I don't know how to connect mytemplate.tpl.php to display my form.
That's example of what I have now in my template: 
`<pre><div class="onelinedd">
     <div class="onedd">
         <div class="column-left">
    <div>Form Field 1</div>
     <strong><?php echo drupal_render($form_data['first']); ?></strong>
   </div>` 
Now instead of my form is showing only `Form Field 1` and `Form Field 2`

Comment: But you're not having problems getting Drupal to actually use your template file? `$form_data` will not exist in your template file. You should only have a variable called `$form`. Print out that variable with `dsm()`, `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

Comment: Thank you hampusn for your help. I still have to learn a lot about this, hope I will figure out it soon. Have a great day ;)

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck!